# Dynamically change the matrix in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup

I have this sheet:

```
  A                B
1 15576907000170   
2 17469701000177
3 8402943000152
4 17469701000177
```

I want to set a dynamic function on column B to check if all the numbers in that row have already appeared in A. So it would look like this:

```
  A                B
1 15576907000170   OK  
2 17469701000177   OK
3 8402943000152    OK
4 17469701000177   NOT OK
```

The closest I got was with this one:

```
= if(isnumber(VLOOKUP(A4;A:A;1;FALSE))=TRUE;"NOT OK"; "OK")
```

However it doesn't work because it will always find the number in column A. In the VLOOKUP I should be able to select only rows above the one from the actual cell, in the example above it would be something like this:

```
= if(isnumber(VLOOKUP(A4;A:A(ROW(A4-1);1;FALSE))=TRUE;"NOT OK"; "OK")
```

However, this gives me a synthax error.
Can anyone help on running this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following formula in `B1` cell then drag and down as needed.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)>1,"Not Ok","Ok")
```

[image]

Comment: Semicolon `(;)` and comma `(,)` depends on regional setting of computer.

Answer (score 2):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)
B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MATCH(A1:A4;A1:A4;0)=ROW(A1:A4);"OK";"NOT OK"))
```

- MATCH to find the first ROW number
- IF first ROW = Current Row,OK,else,NOT OK